# Hibernate @Enumerated as AtomicReference

Tags: java, hibernate, atomic, atomicreference

I have a class that uses Hiberante for database operations and need it to be thread-safe. I am trying refactor the code to use Atomic Variables with its Operations instead of having a synchronized method due to locking as it is breaking the application due to slow performance (a lot of threads are in play) on a high volume of requests but I am having issues with a variable with @Enumeration to refactor to AtomicReference due to an exception:

> Attribute [com.gateway.domain.ImportTypeDetail.importFrequency] was
>   annotated as enumerated, but its java type is not an enum
>   [java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference]

Code before refactor:

```
@Column(name = Constants.Columns.IMPORT_FREQUENCY)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ImportFrequency importFrequency;
```

I refactored to:

```
@Column(name = Constants.Columns.IMPORT_FREQUENCY)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private AtomicReference<ImportFrequency> importFrequency = new AtomicReference<>(ImportFrequency.UNKNOWN);
```

Is it possible to implement AtomicReference in the scenario? EnumType only options are `ORDINAL` and `STRING` for type property or integer and type property or string respectively.

Comment: Your approach is completely wrong. Entities don't need to be thread-safe. You're not supposed to share entities between threads. Your issues won't be solved with the use of `AtomicXXX`, so thankfully Hibernate won't even allow it. You're probably looking at a bigger refactoring.

Comment: @Kayaman ah, okay, didn't know that, thanks! I have refactored all of the DTOs that are in play but still got an exception of `javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)` so figured ImportService needs some refactoring too (I'm new to Atomic and Hibernate by the way and have done research but not a good one it seems)

Comment: Optimistic locking is a whole different thing. `AtomicReference` won't help you there anyway. Don't refactor without knowing what you're doing, and if you're not familiar with Hibernate, you have a lot to learn how it behaves behind the scenes.